# Is it OK to ask a question that will (likely) involve some programming by the answerer?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have thought of a puzzle that I'd like to see the result of about primes. To continue my investigation I need some computer programming.  I have absolutely no experience or even know which program could help.  I am able to detail the puzzle so that someone could continue if they wished but am unsure whether or not this was appropriate? Thanks. Sorry this should be on maths meta.

Comment: In hindsight, your question was not about programming. It was about a particular graph of an abstract (yet un-formalized) discrete function. So, in reality, you allowing computers to be used is no different than using a graphing calculator. I'm merely posting this for future readers as I've seen your resulting question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think there is a principle problem against questions and answers which involve programming. Some mathematicians do a lot of programming as part of their work.

The issue here is the question being on-topic. Namely, it has to be about the mathematics, and not about the implementation. It should be about the general idea behind the algorithm, rather than how to write that algorithm in a specific language.

I find the above to be a generally good outline for CAS (Computer Algebra System) related questions as well, with the small caveat that we can be a bit more lenient about implementation question, as long as they are honestly mathematical (and not, for example, "I tried to run sqrt[2] and it failed, what am I doing wrong" type of tech support).

Comment: Thanks. I'll post it as it is definitely mathematical in content.